# Best XML DB for a PHP website?

Tags: php, xml, database, iis, iis-6

I'm planning on writing a RSS Feed Aggregator with a team, but I'm wondering what XML Database we should use. The server currently runs IIS 6.0 with PHP 5.3.0 x64, I understand already that I need both a server application and a PHP extension.

What I've discovered already:

- Galax

  - Have previously used this at university, but I **can't find information** about it on google, it tends to show information about something else named Galax or the Galaxy...
- [eXist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/)

  - Together with [Phexist](http://query-exist.sourceforge.net/) this seems like a last resort, although it's dated from 2007.
  - Bad documentation.
  - Wondering if it has all features I will need through the development.
- [Sedna](http://modis.ispras.ru/sedna/)

  - Looks professional and does have API support for PHP.
  - Good documentation!
  - Wondering if it has any disadvantages.
- [Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/xml/index.html)

  - Also looks professional, Oracle is well-known and I have heard of Berkeley before...
  - Can't find documentation right away, only an old presentation.
  - I will have to mess around with trying to get the PHP extension to compile.
- [Saxon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/)

  - Hard to [set-up in PHP](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/saxon/index.php?title=Saxon-from-PHP) and seems bloated and unstable when you do so.
- ...

  - Are there any other solutions?
  - Is PHP good enough for this?

I would love to hear your opinions on the best way to accomplish this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 ($$$) has great XML integration - but you pay for it. This is what we use where I work. You will have to (should anyway) be running the latest PHP if you're going to use PDO to interface to it.

I assume you're looking for a database that can natively handle XML.  From my understanding (hearsay) Oracle and MS-SQL also handle XML but they are not as polished.

In the Open Source world I dont know what to recommend for tight XML integration.

-CF

Comment: DB2 Express-C is free and has the XML features that the full DB2 platform has. It's not OSS and you won't get support from IBM with it though.

Comment: The planned project is non-profit, will take a look at DB2 Express-C tomorrow. Thank you for your quick response... :-)

Comment: Have chosen Sedna but you deserve to be the accepted solution. ;-)